# Rcharts: plot only shows first character of label

Tags: r, label, rcharts

I recently switched from ggplot to Rcharts and have a fairly simple question about the labels.

Sample data

```
data_1 <- data.table(Filter = c('Filter 1', 'Filter 2'),
               Amount = c(100, 50))

data_2 <- data.table(Filter = c('Filter 1'),
               Amount = c(100))
```

Plots

```
hPlot(Amount ~ Filter, data = data_1, type = 'bar', group.na = 'NA\'s')
hPlot(Amount ~ Filter, data = data_2, type = 'bar', group.na = 'NA\'s')
```

Question:
Why do we see the correct label in the first plot, but only the first letter of the label in the second plot? This issue always occurs when the number of rows  = 1 (as it is in data_2).

Does anyone has a quick fix / workaround?

Comment: Doesn't look there is much active development of this library and a lot of open issues. https://github.com/ramnathv/rCharts